# Allowing a button to be pressed when control has been passed away

Tags: python, button, tkinter

So I have this button thats made to start stuff, like this

```
self.buttontext = StringVar()
self.buttontext.set("Start")
self.button = Button(self.bottomframe, textvariable=self.buttontext, command=self.start)
```

And when it starts, I want the user to be able to cut it short if they need to by changing the same button to a stop button right after it starts

```
def start(self):
    self.button.config(command=self.stop)
    self.buttontext.set("Stop")
    permission = True
    for ...
        if update:
            run properly
        else:
            end prematurely

    self.button.config(command = self.start)
    self.buttontext.set("Start")
```

That considers a boolean in every iteration of the loop. The stop function will change update to false so that the loop

```
def stop(self):
    permission = False
```

However, after I click 'Start' I guess control is no longer in the mainloop and the buttons are unresponsive, despite the button changing its properties for the duration of the runtime. How can I make the button responsive so that it can be interrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `self.update()` on every iteration of the loop so that the application can service both screen-refresh events and button-press events (assuming `self` refers to a tkinter widget)